# Regex Negation: Handling conditional if statements that cancel the match if fulfilled

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

Say for example I have this text:

`hello world **ant*** lorem **cat** opposum** *** ***antelope*** *rabbit __dog__`

I would like to match strings that only have `**` and `__` as its preceding and concluding characters. So in the case above, the matches that I would only want are "cat" and "dog". This means that I have to cancel or negate the match if there are extra surrounding characters. For example, `***dog**` or `__dog___` should fail.

I've tried to solve this using a negative look around http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html to no avail.

Here's the current pattern I have

```
const pattern = /([^*])\*(\w+)\*([^*])/g;
const match = pattern.exec(text);
const annotatedText = match[0];
const matchedText = match[1];

// Return if annotatedText is a possible match for bolditalic
if (annotatedText.startsWith("***") || annotatedText.startsWith("___")) {
        return;
}
// Return if the matchedText has spaces in between
if (/\s/.test(matchedText)) {
        return;
}
if (text.match(/^([*_ \n]+)$/g)) {
        return;
}
```

in javascript regex,

Essentially, I want to remove the javascript string checks and add the logic on the regex pattern itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
/(?<=(?<!\*)\*\*)\w+(?=\*\*(?!\*))|(?<=(?<!_)__)\w+(?=__(?!_))/gi
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/SQw65v/2/).

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \*                       '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \*                       '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \*                       '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \*                       '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \*                       '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \*                       '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    __                       '__'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    __                       '__'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**JavaScript code**:

```js
const string = 'hello world **ant*** lorem **cat** opposum** *** ***antelope*** *rabbit __dog__';
console.log(string.match(/(?<=(?<!\*)\*\*)\w+(?=\*\*(?!\*))|(?<=(?<!_)__)\w+(?=__(?!_))/gi))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I've tested it and the matching works well. One caveat: is it possible to catch as well the behind and after characters?

So for example: 
`hello world **dog**` should return `**dog**` instead of `dog`

Comment: @wolfgang Even easier: `(?<!\*)\*\*\w+\*\*(?!\*)|(?<!_)__\w+__(?!_)`. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/SQw65v/3). Please consider accepting/upvoting if it works for you.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch, I'll set this as the right solution.